# How do I wrap textures inside shader GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I'm trying out GLSL and one of the problems I'm facing is wrapping a random texture sampler in the shader. Searching for answers on the web first, this leads me to using these:

- glTexParameter()
- GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S GL_REPEAT
- GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T GL_REPEAT

I'm not sure where to put this or how to use it. I'm using a custom engine for this shader and I would assume I could wrap the texture in the shader.

My main concern on this is my final output render having left and bottom artifacts. I got some previous advise it has to do with wrapping a random texture that is used for noise if that helps in my case.

Comment: `fract (tex_coord.st)` will do the same thing, this is not particularly useful knowledge but I thought you might like to know ;)

Comment: Thanks Andon, how do I assign this to the texture? I'm declaring `uniform sampler2D randtex0` as the texture I would like to wrap and not clamp.

Comment: My main concern on this is my final output render having left and bottom artifacts. I got some previous advise it has to do with wrapping a random texture that is used for noise if that helps in my case.

Comment: Oh, really? Can you link to a screenshot illustrating your problem? Those artifacts almost certainly come from linear texture filtering, when you use linear filtering you have to be extremely careful with coordinates at the edges, especially if the texture is a spritesheet / atlas.

Comment: thanks, I have to zoom in and take each area. here it is [Left](http://imgur.com/iMYjcoi,s4tkp2S) and [Bottom](http://imgur.com/iMYjcoi,s4tkp2S#1) screenshots. I did hear some issues about this and I was hoping for a solution.

Comment: Oh wow, I have never seen anything like that before. I really don't know what that is. That's not at all what I was discussing. There might be a floating-point error somewhere, you should try outputting the texture coordinates in your GLSL fragment shader to see if they behave sensibly (they should be a smooth red-green gradient). While you're at it, it might help if you added your vertex and fragment shaders to the question so I can see what you have tried.

Comment: Hey Andon, thank you for the follow up. Actually, it's an old SSAO shader that a forum user/friend referred to me that I just converted. You can check out the code [here](http://pastebin.com/1AmWqTX5). Aside from the artifacts and banding there's also flickering involved when I move/rotate the camera in any direction. I'm really happy with this solution at the moment btw, it's simple and it works. I just need to get rid both of these issues(flickering and banding). I set it to work with GL2 because it's throwing error with GL3. Can you see if it can be improved or fixed?

Answer (score 5):

For people who come here from Google (like me), the shader version is:

```
fract (tex_coord.st)
```

this will loop coordinates in range 0.0 - 1.0

Comment: Wrapping your texture coordinates doesn't help with the problem that sampling at 0.0 or 1.0 with bilinear filtering will get you the average of the opposing pair of edge texels. Texel centers for a 4px image are at `u=1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't set these values in the shader. You set them in your program, generally when first creating the texture (though it can be set or changed whenever).

If you've already uploaded your texture data to OpenGL then all you have to do is this:

First bind the texture if it is not already.

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
```

Then set the parameters.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

Comment: Ok I see, I was thinking more of a direct shader approach like Andon commented above but thank you for this info.

Comment: Just curious - why do you want to do it in the shader if OpenGL will do it for you? The less you have to write in your shader, the less that can go wrong with it and that you have to maintain. If you put it in the shader, it will likely be confusing to anyone (including you) maintaining the code in the future when they set the texture parameter and it doesn't change.

Comment: Actually this is a quick post process filter that I converted and just needs minimal settings and technically all the work is done through the shader file except for material and other shaders.